# is /usr/bin/ authorized as a default location for volume sharing in docker prefrences?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, volumes

I am sharing a docker-compose file with a team member to easily build our app. We're both on OSX and **it works fine** from my machine, but my colleague is getting the following error:

```
ERROR: for backend Cannot start service backend: b'Mounts denied: \r\nThe path /usr/bin/docker\r\nis not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.\r\nYou can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.\r\nSee https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.\r\n.'
```

I assume it is due to the following statement in the docker-compose.yaml.

```
volumes:
  - "/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker"
```

I didn't have to alter my docker-> preferences-> file sharing to make this work. I only have the default dirs shared: `/Users, /Volumes, /tmp, /private`.

How come it isn't working on his machine? Does he have to add the /usr dir as a shared dir? If so, how come I don't have to?

**UPDATE**
The problem was that the docker executable was located in /usr/local/bin/ rather than /usr/bin. I have no idea why docker installed the executable differently despite both machines being OSX.

Answer (score 1):

That's a misleading error, should have asked you to check if the path `/usr/bin/docker` exists on the host machine. Docker (at least on Mac) will attempt to create a directory if it doesn't exist. Apparently, your team mate isn't logged in with sufficient privileges to create /usr/bin/docker.